# How can I log the raw http request/response in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to log the raw http requests/responses in rails?

that is, the plain text http message, including the body, even if the body is binary

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what exactly you want to log. But I believe [`raw_post`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post) is what you are looking for. This will return the raw POST body. You can call this method in any of your methods in the controller.

A similar method exist for getting the GET params: [`raw_params`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html#method-i-raw_params)

If that isn't good enough then a [middleware](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) layer might help.

Comment: Thank you! raw_post is not enough. 
I wonder if there are more straight-forward ways than Rack.

Comment: How about digging into the return value of the [`request`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-POST) method? Rip it open and see what's inside. It has a POST method.

Comment: What I really want is the plain text http message, rather than a rails processed object, in case something unexpected happened during the parsing